# ASP.Net C# Ajax Form Validation and Submit button status

Tags: c#, ajax, validation

I have a quite complicated form, and i would like to validate the form before it is submitted in some nice looking ajax way. As part of this i would also like to only enable the forms submit button once the form is correctly filled in.

I'm using C#/asp.net/jquery

thanks
Luke

Comment: Are you using asp.net validation controls to validate data

Comment: no, i've not got any form side validation on it at present, would i be able to use the asp.net validation controls to control the submit button?

Comment: I have not performed validation with Ajax,but using asp.net validation controls the Page.Validate() method will return true if all validation went right and will return false if there was a problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use ASP.NET validation group and add a validation summary.  The submit button would go in the validation group defined and would only fire once the form meets the validation requirements.

```
<asp:Button ValidationGroup="YourGroupName" runat="server" />
```

Comment: @beakersoft - how did you get on?